# How to render amp-ad with 50% viewport?

Tags: amp-html, amp-ad

Is it possible to configure or implement viewport check and inside amp-ad?

Only solution that I could reach was `data-loading-strategy="0"`, but this approach loads ad on 0% ~ 1% viewport...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution via `window.context.observeIntersection`.

Docs: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/main/ads/README.md#ad-viewability